# How to get form (connected with generic contenttype to model in detailview) in CreateView into DetailView?

Tags: django

I tried with FormMixins in DetailView and got my form, but the problem is obviously that they can't have the same view at all, or atleast not the same URL, so how does this work? I also tried with a post() function in the class.

How would you manage a form that you need in several places on the same page(preferably using the built in class based views) and still have it recieve the id of the detail model?

Edit: Actually we have the exact same example here on stack, how does stack make it possible to have answer/comments forms everywhere?

Edit2: I have the below code thanks to Alasdair now, but get error NOT NULL constraint failed publish_answer.post_id

```
class PostDetailView(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Post
    form_class = AnswerForm
    template_name = 'main/postdetail.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = AnswerForm(initial={'post': self.object})
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(PostDetailView, self).form_valid(form)
```

answerform

```
class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=PagedownWidget())

    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ('content',)
```

URL

```
path('subject/<slug>', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='postdetail'),
```

I have get_absolute_url in the model for Post, "postdetail".

To add to the answer I got, I would like to inform you of this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#an-alternative-better-solution

Comment: The docs on [Using mixins with class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/mixins/) might help, in particular the [Using FormMixin with DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-formmixin-with-detailview) section.

Comment: @Alasdair Thank you very much, i updated my code and question but got a error

Comment: Please show your `AnswerForm`, URL pattern, and the full traceback.

Comment: @Alasdair Updated with answerform, but when I added 'post' and 'created_by' in the fields there, so they showed up, I manually selected them and the answer was saved. I'm not sure how to automate this in this kind of view? I'm open for every suggestion, I just do this for learning and procrastinating on my exam.

Comment: @Alasdair Updated now, sorry. I think the last step is to just automate filling in post id and created_by id in the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `post` and `created_by` fields in the `form_valid` method, after saving the form with `commit=False`. See the docs on [the model form save method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) for more info.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.created_by = self.request.user
    instance.post = self.object
    instance.save()
    return super(PostDetailView, self).form_valid(form)
```

You may want to use [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) so that only logged-in users can access the view.

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class PostDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, DetailView):
```

If you want all users to be able to access the view but only logged-in users to be able to submit the form, then it gets more complicated. I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader, but note that the docs on [using FormMixin with DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-formmixin-with-detailview) finally decide to create a separate view to handle the post request.

Comment: Thanks! Your link to the documentation and this answer was very helpful! I would also vote if i could